# What does "RA" mean in the FAA Terminal Constraints?

Tags: weather, terminology, faa, air-traffic-management

I'm trying to interpret the Terminal Constraints listed on the Operations Plan Advisory (https://www.fly.faa.gov/adv/adv_spt.jsp). RA seems to be used in the context of weather, but I haven't been able to find a definition for what "RA" means other than "Resolution Advisory" which I don't think is applicable in this context.

Example:

```
TERMINAL CONSTRAINTS:
NY METS/PHL/DC METS-RA/LOCIGS
CTL/ATL/MCO/TPA/FLL/MIA-RA/TSTMS
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

-RA is the METAR code for light rain.

LOCIGS is low ceilings, and TSTMS is thunderstorms.*

---

* [Air Traffic Management Glossary of Terms](https://www.fly.faa.gov/Products/Glossary_of_Terms/glossary_of_terms.html) (faa.gov).

Comment: If you can link to a reference that might be helpful for the OP

Comment: In this case, I believe the "-" is just a hyphen to separate the fields, not an indication the rain is light. All the terminal constraints use a hyphen between the airport name(s) and the conditions, e.g. "LAX-RWY 07L/25R CLOSED THROUGH 05/24/18." While -RA is light rain in a METAR/TAF context, this seems like more of an informal usage.

Comment: Could be, but I only see the hyphen used in front of those letters.

Comment: @ZachLipton No, the hypen means light. A space (or no character) means moderate and a + means heavy. This is defined precisely by ICAO annex 3 appendix 3 chapter 4 (don't remember the exact paragraph).

Comment: @Jupiter In a METAR, absolutely. But this isn't a METAR; it's an airspace planning document. Look at the current version. It says "MSP/ORD/MDW/CLT/MEM/DFW/DAL/IAH/HOU/DEN-TSTMS" Presumably that's a list of airports, a hyphen, and thunderstorms, not an indication that there are "light thunderstorms" in the vicinity of all of those airports. The next line says "PDX-RWY 1OL/28R CL0SED," and surely there's not a "light runway closure." I don't know for sure, but it doesn't seem like it means light in this context.